# Drop a localdb database from VS package manager

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, scripting, localdb

I would like to be able to write a simple script to be able to drop a localdb database at will.

First I have to stop the instance to kill any active connections by running this in the VS package manager

```
SqlLocalDB.exe stop v11.0
```

Then I need to drop the db which I have to do by connecting to `(localdb)\v11.0` master db with Linqpad or SSMS

```
DROP DATABASE MyDb
```

But I don't *want* to switch windows to do this, I'd like to just write a script. I can't figure out how to execute the second query from the command line. I've tried this

```
SQLCMD.EXE -s "(localdb)\v11.0" -d "master" -q "drop database MyDb"
```

which gives me an error

```
SQLCMD.EXE : Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: 
Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .
```

Comment: You just stopped the instance, so of course sqlcmd cannot connect to it.

Comment: @ErikEJ I believe localdb starts up when you try to connect to it. Also I should clarify that *all* queries (even when I don't stop the instance) fail with the same error message. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Are you sure you are using a "new" version of sqlcmd.exe?

Comment: @ErikEJ `PM> SQLCMD.EXE -? /
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool /
Version 11.0.2100.60 NT x64`. Are you saying that what I have above should work?

Comment: Maybe use a capital letter "-S"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197802/how-to-connect-sqlcmd-to-the-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it should work if you use a capital letter "S"

```
SQLCMD.EXE -S "(localdb)\v11.0" -d "master" -Q "drop database MyDb"
```

You'd probably also want to use a capital "Q" so that sqlcmd will exit immediately.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Ah, yes now I can connect. Still having issues with "Login failed for user" (which is weird, I assumed it would use integrated security), but that's another issue.

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2020, you can just type:

```
Drop-Database
```

in the Package Manager console and it should work:

```
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Drop-Database" on target "database 'databasename' on server '(localdb)\mssqllocaldb'".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):y
```

If it doesn't work, you might need to manually install [Entity Framework Core tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell).